# Lebesgue measure and matrix notation problem

Tags: measure-theory

I have trouble with understanding following from my text book in Measures and Integral theory.

> Let T be an orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix. If $\lambda^{n}$ is the Lebesgue measure then we have: $\lambda^{n} = T(\lambda^{n})$

And my question is:

**How to interpret the $T(\lambda^{n})$-part?**

How is it possible to multiply a $n\times n$ matrix with a real number ($\lambda^{n}$ is a measure and therefore it is a value between 0 and $\infty$)?

Comment: A measure is not a number. A measure associates numerical values to measurable sets and those values range between $0$ and $\infty$. I am however also puzzled by the notation. I suppose $\lambda^n$ means the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the statement means that this measure is invariant under orthogonal transformations.

Comment: $\lambda^{n}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. I know a measure is a map. But how to take a $n\times n$ matrix T to a map which is not a $n$ vector, but which output is a real number?

Comment: Actually $T(\lambda^n)$ is a notation for $\lambda^n\circ T$. Which means you apply $T$ to whatever measurable set you feed to your measure and then compute the measure.

Comment: Ahhh.. That makes sense! Thanks! :D

Comment: Is [this](http://books.google.es/books/about/Measure_and_Integral.html?hl=es&id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC) your book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T(\lambda^n)$ is just notation for $\lambda^n \circ T$, i.e. apply the transformation T on the set before calculating its measure. So, what one asks to prove is for any measurable set $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ you have to show that

$$\lambda^n(B)=T(\lambda^n)(B)\equiv\lambda^n\circ T(B)\equiv\lambda^n(T(B)) \; .$$